# Software for still images from a video capture card

Tags: video, video-editing

I have a video card that is connected to my PC and I would like to capture the video in real time and be able to record still images at will. Could you recommend a particular software for this task?

P.S: I tried the software **VirtualDub** for capturing the video yet could not realize if it offers capturing still images.

Answer (score 1):

For end-user software, you may want to check out [DaVinci Resolve](https://www.blackmagicdesign.com/products/davinciresolve) or [Lightworks](https://www.lwks.com/).

For developing an application, I would recommend using the [LEADTOOLS Multimedia SDK](https://www.leadtools.com/sdk/engine/multimedia). This library contains programmatic interfaces for C, C++, COM, and .NET applications. Developers can use the CaptureCtrl for capturing from local hardware to file and use the GetStillImage() method or LEAD Video Callback filter for getting stills.